# Ebean looks for wrong sequence name in Play Framework 2

Tags: java, postgresql, orm, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have an id:

```
@Column(name = "device")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "device_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "device_gen", sequenceName = "device_id")
@Id
public Integer id;
```

SequenceGenerator defines the sequenceName as `device_id` but trying to save an entity I get the error: **relation "public.device_seq" does not exist**.

Why is it looking for `device_seq` instead of `device_id`?

I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: I know Anorm had similar issues (with prefixes) due to PostgreSQL JDBC driver, so I suspect that's the case, but I can't guarantee it. If you could try and make sure this works in MySQL, then you could raise a bug for Play/Ebeans on it.

Comment: @PereVillega I know it works with H2. When I have time I will look into trying it with MySQL

Comment: if it works with h2, then please raise the bug in Play and Ebeans forums, as it is likely a bug in one of them. They may know a workaround

Comment: @PereVillega Now that I am looking at the project I see that I was lying about H2. I had en existing PostgreSQL database, and H2 was evolved by play itself.

Comment: @RobFox Was that the solution? If so you should post with an explanation in case someone else runs across this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="device_gen")
```